# Get item workflow state name

Tags: workflow

We would like to get workflow state name of the item. I tried to find on internet  but did not get any relevant result.

Could someone help me out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Sitecore PowerShell script then you try this :-

```
$contentItem = Get-Item "master:path.."
(Get-Item master: -ID $contentItem."__Workflow state").Name
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the workflow state using the below `PowerShell` script:

```
$item = Get-Item master:/sitecore/content/Home | Get-ItemField -IncludeStandardFields -ReturnType Field -Name "*" 
$item | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Name -eq '__Workflow state') {
        (Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID $_.Value).Name 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have assumed that you mean in .NET and not SPE.

If an item has a workflow state, you will be able access the name of that state by using one of the following ways:

1. Through use of the Sitecore workflow state field directly:

   ```
   var workflowState = (Sitecore.Data.Fields.ReferenceField)Sitecore.Context.Item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.WorkflowState];
   var workflowStateName = workflowState.TargetItem.DisplayName;
   ```
2. Using the workflow provider

   ```
    var workflow = Sitecore.Context.Database.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(Sitecore.Context.Item);
    var workflowState = workflow.GetState(Sitecore.Context.Item);
    var workflowStateName = workflowState.DisplayName;
   ```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

To get the workflow state you can use :

```
var workflowStateItemid=currentItem["__Workflow state"];
var workflowStateItem=Sitecore.Context.Dabase.GetItem(new ID(workflowStateItemid));
var workflowStateItemName=workflowStateItem.Name;
```

Comment: Could you assist me how I can get workflow state of the item in Sitecore power shell script ?